# Apache2 Rewrite, remove file extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### Question

With an apache rewrite, when a user inputs:

```
example.com/home/
OR
example.com/home
```

The website will send the user to:

```
example.com/home.php
```

but the url will continue to be:

```
example.com/home/
```

### My broken solution

My current code in .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(home/)$ home.php [NC,L]
```

but it seems to redirect the user to "home.php.php.php.php" and so on.

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is a **bad** idea to have both `example.com/home/` and `example.com/home` leading to same content (duplicate content is not appreciate by search engines like Google).

Then, you have to disable `MultiViews` to get the behaviour you want.

You can try with this code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/$ /home.php [NC,L] 
# or ^home$ if you don't want it with trailing slash
```

Comment: ^home/$ kind of works, only all my css and js look at www/home/ instead of www/. ^home$ gives no errors, but sends me to home.php.php.php.php.php

Comment: If you use `home/` then it's a normal behaviour if you're using relative paths. Try adding a slash before all your css and js

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You can access any PHP file without php extension :)

Comment: I get the error message in apache2/error.log: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/home (None could be negotiated). Zlib: Compressed 282 to 215 : URL /home/ It then sends me to my 404 page.